# Sending a message to the content script on closing a Firefox sidebar

Tags: addeventlistener, firefox-addon-webextensions, content-script, firefox-sidebar

Because our sidebar Web extension modifies the HTML content displayed in the Web browser, we would want to clear the page back once we close the sidebar.

Therefore I tried this:

### sidebar.js

```js
(...)
class Sidebar extends React.Component {

  (...)
  componentDidMount() {
    (...)

    // on closing the sidebar
    window.addEventListener('pagehide', () => {
      console.log('Calling erase on tab', this.state.tabId);
      browser.tabs.sendMessage(this.state.tabId, {aim: 'erase'});
      console.log('AFTER');
    });

  }
  (...)
}

const panel = document.getElementById('panel');
ReactDOM.render(<Sidebar />, panel);
```

### content.js

```js
(...)
const messageHandler = async (message) => {
  console.log('CALL:', message);
  switch (message.aim) {
    case 'erase':
      erase();
      return true;
      (...)
    }
  }
};

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messageHandler);
```

When closing the sidebar, the result in the browser console is:

```
Calling erase on tab 1
AFTER
```

And **nothing** is displayed in the Web console, although *other* messages were shown in the `CALL <message>` format before closing.

I suspected that `sidebar.js` might be quitting before the message is sent to `content.js`. Hence I added `await` and `async` to the event listener:

```js
    window.addEventListener('pagehide', async () => {
      console.log('Calling erase on tab', this.state.tabId);
      await browser.tabs.sendMessage(this.state.tabId, {aim: 'erase'});
      console.log('AFTER');
    });
```

Then on closing the sidebar, the result in the browser console is (with not `AFTER`):

```
Calling erase on tab 1
```

And still **nothing** is displayed in the Web console, although *other* messages were shown in the `CALL <message>` format before closing.

Comment: Did you try returning a response like the sendMessage API example?  Might give more clues.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage